# HTML input - Replace selected value by typing

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick

I have the below `input` that the user can first click to enable (`button1`), type the desired new value, and finally save it (`button2`).

```
<input class="form-control inputUserValue" onkeypress="return contoso.isNumberKey(this, event,3);"
data-default_value="10,00" value="10,00" disabled="">
```

**The issue**: after the field is enabled, the user has **first** to erase the input content with `delete` or `backspace` at keyboard (*including when the content is already selected*) and **then** start typing the new value at the blank `input` field. So, the user can't simply use the mouse to select and just type the new value. This behaviour also occurs at other sections of the software when the `input` is text.

The idea is to improve the user experience by making it possible to just type the desired new value after `button1` pressed, replacing existing and displayed content. The existing text/value should still be displayed, but already selected and ready to be replaced if the user types, or the user may want to deselect and make same minor adjust at the existing text/value.

We've tried `onclick="this.select();"` when `button1` pressed, but still we couldn't type the new value without `delete` or `backspace` first.

Can anyone help on how to achieve this?

The HTML is generated and managed with JS. The `input` is whitin a `table-responsive`. Our system is designed to work on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right way to use the `select()` method, but you first need to `focus()` the input:

```js
usrinput.focus();
usrinput.select();
```

**Working example:** (for input type `text`)

```js
const usrinput = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('#button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  usrinput.disabled = false;
  usrinput.focus();
  usrinput.select();
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">enable</button>
<input type="text" value="10,00" disabled>

<button id="button2">Save</button>
```

---

**Working example:** (for input type `number`)

```js
const usrinput = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('#button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  usrinput.disabled = false;
  usrinput.focus();
  usrinput.select();
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">enable</button>
<input type="number" value="10" disabled>

<button id="button2">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but please notice that the solution should also apply for text input. So, erase the original content is not suitable. If this may seems ok with numbers, this doesn't work well with text (sometimes the users just want to edit a specific segment, not retype everything).

Comment: I added now two input types: ``text`` and ``number``. If that is not what you are looking for, please be more specific...

Comment: The existing text/value should still be displayed, but already selected and ready to be replaced if the user types, or the user may want to deselect and make same minor adjust at the existing text/value.

Comment: Ahh, now i see. I update my answer again...